# Advise on Google Chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to get a dynamic chart from google sheet data which is stored on the tab named 'Data' (range A1:C6, Headers- Date, Sales & Expense) to google WebApp. I have given the codes below, but the page is showing "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string". I am not sure where am I doing it wrong, if anyone could please advise.

Code.gs:

```
function doGet(){
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("chart").evaluate();
 
}

function getStats(){

const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(),3).getDisplayValues();
    
}
```

Chart.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData);

      function getData(){

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getStats();

      }

      function drawChart(dataReturned) {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataReturned);

      
          var options = {
          title: 'Sales and Expenses',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your script and your question, I thought that the reason for your issue might be due to that the values are retrieved by `getDisplayValues()`. In this case, all values are string type.

If your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function getStats() {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  return ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 3).getValues().map(([a, b, c]) => [a instanceof Date ? a.toISOString() : a, b, c]); // Modified
}
```

- Here, from your script and question, I guessed that the 1st row is the header row like "Date", "Sales" and "Expense". If your 1st row is not the header, please set them.

#### HTML & Javascript side:

##### From:

```js
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataReturned);
```

##### To:

```js
dataReturned = dataReturned.map(([a, b, c], i) => [i == 0 ? a : new Date(a), b, c]); // Added
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataReturned);
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Dates and Times of Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)